# Beaglebone Black - What is the "magic" field in the board ID header structure?

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

Beaglebone's bootloader (U-Boot) seems to check for the magic number to determine the board ID. The magic number is a hexadecimal value of "0xEE3355AA". Is this simply a unique number that was randomly chosen? Or does this value carry more information?

```html
struct am335x_baseboard_id {
        unsigned int  magic;
        char name[HDR_NAME_LEN];
        char version[4];
        char serial[12];
        char config[32];
        char mac_addr[HDR_NO_OF_MAC_ADDR][HDR_ETH_ALEN];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

U-boot uses it to identify the board as a BeagleBone.

0xEE3355AA says its the production version